# What will be the best way to send update from server to iphone?

Tags: php, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm Just developing IOS App, And i can easily post data from the Iphone to server and get the response back..
The problem starting when someone update values in the server side (From a website), And now i have to "post" the changes to the iphone and update the table changes - there.

Is there a way to communicate from the Server to iphone to transfer data? I thought to use push notifications, The thing is that i don't know if i can trust it (What if the app is not running? i don't want to notify the user that he made changes, i simply want to update the iphone so it will call a function that will update its tables..)

The Server language is PHP.

Hope it clear enough..

Thank you!

Eran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can achieve:

- Let the iPhone app request the server data with an interval (polling, e.g. every 10 seconds). This is only useful if the updates can be forwarded with a small delay. Another drawback is that your server load will be a bit higher because of the many requests
- Open a [socket](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) between the server and the iphone app. You can use [CocoaASyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) for this. You can send messages to your iphone app every moment you want. If the iPhone app is closed, you can close the socket connection and the user won't receive updates anymore

Comment: That's Great, Ill Try the Socket idea.. Thank you!